# Can't reach full line rate on two 10Gbps interfaces simultaneously

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, networking

I'm working on application which generates real time data flow with throughput of tens Gbit/s. I don't need any response so I use UDP. I send packets to multicast address. My system (Centos 7) has 2 network ports of 10 Gbit/s per each.

I faced a trouble when I try to send data over both ports at the same time. I expected something a little bit less 20 Gbit/s but actually I got 11-12 Gbit. If use 1 port only I get 9.5 Gbit/s as it should be.

I use select() and non-blocking sockets. Here is executable demo:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
// #include <sys/resource.h>



#define GROUP_PORT 3490
#define GROUP_ADDR "225.0.0.37"
#define INTERFACES 2
#define LOCAL_INTERFACE_IP0 "192.168.2.3"
#define LOCAL_INTERFACE_IP1 "192.168.2.4"



inline long duration_mcs(timespec t1, timespec t2) {
    return ((t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec)*1000000+(t2.tv_nsec - t1.tv_nsec)/1000);
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    // if (setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, -15) == -1) {
    //     printf("PRIO failed: %s.\n", std::strerror(errno));
    //     return -1;
    // }

    //bind thread to specific core
    cpu_set_t set;
    CPU_ZERO(&set); //clear cpu set
    int cpuId = 5;
    CPU_SET(cpuId, &set); //dedicate cpu for current thread (add cpuId to set)
    //bind current thread (pId=0) to dedicated cpu
    if (sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(set), &set) == -1) {
        printf("sched_setaffinity failed: %s.\n", std::strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }


    // SETUP INTERFACES ADDRESSES ----------------------------------
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    in_addr localInterface[INTERFACES];
    localInterface[0].s_addr = inet_addr(LOCAL_INTERFACE_IP0);
    localInterface[1].s_addr = inet_addr(LOCAL_INTERFACE_IP1);


    // SETUP SOCKETS -----------------------------------------------
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    int fdmax = 0;
    int fds[INTERFACES];
    int flags;

    for (int i=0; i<INTERFACES; ++i) {
        fds[i] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if (fds[i] == -1) {
            printf("Socket %d failed: %s.\n", i, std::strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }

        //make sockets NONBLOCK
        if ((flags = fcntl(fds[i], F_GETFL, 0)) < 0) 
        {
            printf("F_GETFL on socket %d failed: %s.\n", i, std::strerror(errno));
        }

        if (fcntl(fds[i], F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) < 0) 
        {
            printf("O_NONBLOCK on socket %d failed: %s.\n", i, std::strerror(errno));
        }

        if (fds[i] > fdmax) fdmax = fds[i];
        printf("Socket %d success.\n", i);
    }



    // SETUP SOCKET OPTIONS ----------------------------------------
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    // send packets through particular interface
    for (int i=0; i<INTERFACES; ++i) {
        if (setsockopt(fds[i], IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char*) &localInterface[i], sizeof(localInterface[i])) == -1) {
            printf("IP_MULTICAST_IF on interface %s failed: %s.\n", inet_ntoa(localInterface[i]),  std::strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
    }

    // disable multicast loop
    char loopch=0;
    for (int i=0; i<INTERFACES; ++i) {
        if (setsockopt(fds[i], IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, (char*) &loopch, sizeof(loopch)) == -1) {
            printf("IP_MULTICAST_LOOP on interface %s failed: %s.\n", inet_ntoa(localInterface[i]), std::strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
    }


    // SETUP ADDRESS STRUCTURE FOR SENDING PACKETS TO --------------
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    sockaddr_in address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(GROUP_PORT);
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(GROUP_ADDR);


    // SETUP DATA BUFFER -------------------------------------------
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t buf_size = 50000;
    char* buffer = (char*) memalign(256, buf_size);


    // SETUP SELECT() STRUCTURES -----------------------------------
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    fd_set master, writefds;
    FD_ZERO(&master);
    FD_ZERO(&writefds);
    for (int i=0; i<INTERFACES; ++i) {
        FD_SET(fds[i], &master);
    }


    // SENDING PACKETS ---------------------------------------------
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t packets = 10000; //number of packets to send
    size_t nbytes = 0;
    int snt;

    bool pckt_flag = false; //flag for all packets are sent

    size_t cnt[INTERFACES]; //counter for sent packets per each interface
    for (int ifs=0; ifs<INTERFACES; ++ifs) cnt[ifs] = 0;

    timespec t1, t2;
    timespec t1_sel, t2_sel;
    timespec t1_proc, t2_proc;
    timespec t1_snd, t2_snd;
    long tsum_sel = 0, tsum_proc = 0, tsum_snd = 0;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &t1);

    while (!pckt_flag) {
        writefds = master;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &t1_sel);
        if (select(fdmax+1, NULL, &writefds, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
            printf("select() failed: %s.\n", std::strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &t2_sel);
        tsum_sel += duration_mcs(t1_sel, t2_sel);

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &t1_proc);
        for (int ifs=0; ifs<INTERFACES; ++ifs) {
            if (FD_ISSET(fds[ifs], &writefds)) {
                //check for how many packets were sent over the interface
                if (cnt[ifs] < packets) {

                    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &t1_snd);
                    snt = sendto(fds[ifs], buffer, buf_size, 0, (sockaddr*) &address, sizeof(address));
                    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &t2_snd);
                    tsum_snd += duration_mcs(t1_snd, t2_snd);

                    if (snt < buf_size) {
                        printf("Sending error: sent %d of %d bytes\n", snt, buf_size);
                    } else {
                        nbytes += snt;
                        ++cnt[ifs];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //renew flag
        pckt_flag = true;
        for (int ifs=0; ifs<INTERFACES; ++ifs) {
            pckt_flag = (pckt_flag && (cnt[ifs] == packets));
        }
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &t2_proc);
        tsum_proc += duration_mcs(t1_proc, t2_proc);
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &t2);

    size_t traf_tot_bytes = nbytes;
    double duration_sec = (double) duration_mcs(t1, t2)/1000000;

    printf("Time %f s.\n", duration_sec);
    printf("Total bytes sent %d.\n", traf_tot_bytes);
    printf("Total throughput %f Gbit/s.\n", 8*(traf_tot_bytes/duration_sec)/1000000000);
    printf("Packets sent by interfaces %d/%d\n", cnt[0], cnt[1]);
    printf("tsum_sel = %d\n", tsum_sel);
    printf("tsum_proc = %d\n", tsum_proc);
    printf("tsum_snd = %d\n", tsum_snd);


    free(buffer);

    return 0;

}
```

In this demo I inserted timers for total time spent on waiting for **select()** (tsum_sel), packets processing (tsum_proc) and sending by **sendto()** itself (tsum_snd).

Output on my system with INTERFACE = 1:

```
Socket 0 success.
Time 0.429122 s.
Total bytes sent 500000000.
Total throughput 9.321358 Gbit/s.
Packets sent by interfaces 10000/0
tsum_sel = 51086
tsum_proc = 362756
tsum_snd = 358939
```

and for INTERFACE = 2:

```
Socket 0 success.
Socket 1 success.
Time 0.697962 s.
Total bytes sent 1000000000.
Total throughput 11.461942 Gbit/s.
Packets sent by interfaces 10000/10000
tsum_sel = 2383
tsum_proc = 662971
tsum_snd = 652629
```

I see that almost all time is consumed by **sendto()** function. So it looks like I send packet over 1st interface, wait for sendto returns and then send to 2nd interface. To avoid that I made my sockets non-blocking. I do not understand what is going on.

My questions are:

1) Why this code doesn't send data with 20 Gbit/s rate?

2) Why non-blocking sendto() takes so much time?

3) How to get 20 Gbit/s here?

Comment: Your run time is less than a second. With such a short sampling interval, these statistics are mostly  meaningless. Things like preemptive multitasking, and paging, come into play. And I would seriously question that the system clock resolution is sufficient enough to establish a meaningful result. Furthermore, even though you have two physical ports, if they're all connected to the same switch, you shouldn't expect much.

Comment: You did not config your SO_SNDBUF socket option. Set it to something BIG like 1MB or so, then try again...

Comment: @Malkocoglu. I set SO_SNDBUF to 4 MB. The trouble remains.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik. I increased number of packets to send. New output: Time 50.218029 s. Total bytes sent 1215752192. Total throughput 15.930534 Gbit/s. Much better but not enough.

Comment: Congratulations, you've pretty much reached the max bandwidth one can reasonably expect. You'll never get 20 gbps from dual bonded link, like that. I would expect around 15-18gbps to be the most that can be obtained. That, pretty much, is the ceiling for all but 16 channel PCI Express 4.0, according to a brief Google search. Are you NICs 16 channel PCIE 4.0 cards?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik. My NIC is PCIe v2.0 x8 lanes. In according to specifications it gives 32 Gbit/s. I agree I will never get 20 Gbps but 18 Gbps I suppose is reachable.

Comment: Not according to public documentation. For PCIe 2, you [need 32 lanes to reach 16gbps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#History_and_revisions).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think your comments deserve to be posted as an answer.

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 +1

Comment: What if you run two copies of the program with INTERFACES=1?  You'd want to set CPU affinity to two different cores.

Comment: @John Zwinck I'm working on that right now. I don't like this way very much because of I need my cores for other calculations and spend 2 of them just for networking is wasteful. Anyway I'll report on results here.

Comment: Non-blocking and asynchronous are two totally different things. You want either truly asynchronous IO or two independent threads.

Comment: @John Zwinck Thanks for new name of the topic. It's much better than mine.

Comment: @n.m. I'll try 2 threads on 1 core and 2 cores.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik PCIe 2.0 x8 is completely sufficient for 20 Gbit/s - it seems, you were looking at GB/s. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got 19 Gbit/s.

I made 2 threads - each sends data independently. It looks simple but there are few shades. If I bind threads to the same virtual core - the problem remains - it gives 14-15 Gbit/s. It works well only if I bind threads to different virtual cores. Even these cores are on the same physical core. This is the best I could wish. I can use 1 physical core for system maintaining and networking.

Thank you all guys who commented.